# Set position and size of a ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, clickonce

I would like to know if there is any way to set a position and a size of a ClickOnce deployed application, started via Process.Start. With normal (.exe) applications there is no problem, I can do something like that:

```
var externalAppProcess = Process.Start("calc");
var externalAppPtr = externalAppProcess.MainWindowHandle;
```

and then use invoked MoveWindow to set stuff like position, size etc. However, when I'm starting an appref-ms file, it runs without any issues, but I can't access its MainWindowHandle, it says that "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you launch *.appref-ms, rundll32 or dfshim process will run. It does ClickOnce checking and eventually starts executable of ClickOnce deployed application.

So you may try finding main window handle like this:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ClickOnceDeployedApp");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;

    // do something
}
```